# Why doesn't viewport scale this image for mobile devices? it's not responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, meta

I'm trying to make my website responsive to mobile and tablets. I know one way of making it responsive is by including this meta tag:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

But when I view my website on mobile, this is the only image that doesn't scale.

```
<div class="container">

<div style="background:transparent !important" class="jumbotron text-center"><h1>built from the ground up</h1>

<img src="http://www.dotnettricks.com/img/nodejs/mean.png" alt="hrrysn">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The viewport meta tag is the right place to start but it's not enough at all. A quick-and-dirty fix might be `max-width: 100%` applied to the image but it really depends on your code rather than the image itself and without having the code it's hard to guess.

Here are [some](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/) [additional](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/) [sources](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images) that might be of assistance.

Cheers!

Martin

Comment: You really helped me out and answered the question even when i couldn't put the actual code down. THANKS